# Python Quicksort Debugging

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, sorting, debugging, quicksort

I have implemented this quicksort but I seem to have bug that I can not fix, would someone mind taking a quick look at it?

The output for the example I give is close to the answer but some indices are misplaced.

---

```
def partition(array, pivot, start, end):

    # move pivot to the end
    temp = array[pivot]
    array[pivot] = array[end]
    array[end] = temp

    i = start
    j = end - 1 

    while(i < j):

        # check from left for element bigger than pivot
        while(i < j and array[end] > array[i]):
            i = i + 1
        # check from right for element smaller than pivot
        while(i < j and array[end] < array[j]):
            j = j - 1

        # if we find a pair of misplaced elements swap them
        if(i < j):
            temp = array[i]
            array[i] = array[j]
            array[j] = temp

    # move pivot element to its position
    temp = array[i]
    array[i] = array[end]
    array[end] = temp

    # return pivot position
    return i

def quicksort_helper(array, start, end):
    if(start < end):
        pivot = (start + end) / 2
        r = partition(array, pivot, start, end)
        quicksort_helper(array, start, r - 1)
        quicksort_helper(array, r + 1, end)

def quicksort(array):
    quicksort_helper(array, 0, len(array) - 1)

array = [6, 0, 5, 1, 3, 4, -1, 10, 2, 7, 8, 9]
quicksort(array)
print array
```

---

I have a feeling the answer will be obvious but I can not find it.

Desired output:

```
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Actual output:

```
[-1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Yes, go obtain a rubber duck and it'll do the job. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: So I probably should have mentioned that I have a similar solution that works where I change i < j to i <= j but I have had a hard time proving to myself that it is correct. I made it open ended like this so someone would give a detailed explanation as to why but I guess that backfired lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical repair is in the inner `while` loops, where you march **i** and **j** toward each other.  If all you're worried about is swapping the correct non-pivot elements, the logic you posted is fine.  However, that first loop needs to be

```
    while(i <= j and array[end] > array[i]):
        i = i + 1
```

to ensure that **i** has the correct value for swapping the pivot element into the middle.  Otherwise, you can swap it one element to the left of its proper position, which is why your sort fails.

You can also use Python's multiple assignment for a cleaner swap:

```
while(i < j):

    # check from left for element bigger than pivot
    while(i <= j and array[end] > array[i]):
        i = i + 1
    # check from right for element smaller than pivot
    while(i < j and array[end] < array[j]):
        j = j - 1

    # if we find a pair of misplaced elements swap them
    if(i < j):
        array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
```

Comment: Preciate the answer bro, that made me understand and thanks for the multiple assignment tip I never knew that!